# How to install latest version of NGINX on Debian?

Tags: debian, package-management, nginx

**Question**: How do I install the latest version of NGINX on Debian?

Comment: **Answer:** Use the nginx repo as documented [here](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html)

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you say "latest" - do you mean the latest available in your Debian version (which version is that, BTW) or the very latest nightly builds from the project?

Answer (score 2):

As documented on [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#Debian)

Install the prerequisites:

```
sudo apt install curl gnupg2 ca-certificates lsb-release debian-archive-keyring
```

Import an official nginx signing key so apt could verify the packages authenticity. Fetch the key:

```
curl https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | gpg --dearmor \
    | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null
```

Verify that the downloaded file contains the proper key:

```
gpg --dry-run --quiet --import --import-options import-show /usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg
```

The output should contain the full fingerprint 573BFD6B3D8FBC641079A6ABABF5BD827BD9BF62 as follows:

```
pub   rsa2048 2011-08-19 [SC] [expires: 2024-06-14]
      573BFD6B3D8FBC641079A6ABABF5BD827BD9BF62
uid                      nginx signing key <signing-key@nginx.com>
```

If the fingerprint is different, remove the file.

To set up the apt repository for stable nginx packages, run the following command:

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg] \
http://nginx.org/packages/debian `lsb_release -cs` nginx" \
    | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
```

If you would like to use mainline nginx packages, run the following command instead:

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg] \
http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian `lsb_release -cs` nginx" \
    | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
```

Set up repository pinning to prefer our packages over distribution-provided ones:

```
echo -e "Package: *\nPin: origin nginx.org\nPin: release o=nginx\nPin-Priority: 900\n" \
    | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/99nginx
```

To install nginx, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nginx
```

Comment: @GAD3R - not sure why you felt the need to change the instructions - I posted what is in the **official** nginx instructions

Comment: I know the difference - if you have an issue with using `$(stuff)` vs `\`stuff\`` then tell the good people at nginx - also if your particular install fails, then, again, tell the good people at nginx